# SOAP service missing values in response

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am missing a value in the SOAP response. I cannot see the value in both print_r as well as __getLastResponse. I am logging the response in the server side before returning the response and I can see the missing value 'contentListRef' and it is not empty.

From what I researched it seems like the data is lost during SOAP parsing but I dont understand how to fix it. The WSDL caching is disabled. Any guidance to fix this issue?

The print_r of the response gives the following

```
stdClass Object
(
    [questions] => stdClass Object
        (
            [multipleChoiceQuestion] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [label] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [text] => Search type:
                            [dir] => ltr
                        )

                    [choices] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [choice] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [label] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [text] => Basic
                                                    [dir] => ltr
                                                )

                                            [id] => search_type_basic
                                        )                                        

                                )

                        )

                    [id] => search_type
                    [allowMultipleSelections] => 
                )

            [inputQuestion] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [inputTypes] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [input] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [type] => TEXT_ALPHANUMERIC
                                )

                        )

                    [label] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [text] => Search type:
                            [dir] => ltr
                        )

                    [id] => search_box
                )

        )

)
```

__getLastResponse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://www.daisy.org/ns/daisy-online/">
<env:Body>
<ns1:getQuestionsResponse>
<ns1:questions>
<ns1:multipleChoiceQuestion id="search_type" allowMultipleSelections="false">
<ns1:label dir="ltr">
<ns1:text>Search type:</ns1:text>
</ns1:label>
<ns1:choices>
<ns1:choice id="search_type_basic">
<ns1:label dir="ltr">
<ns1:text>Basic</ns1:text>
</ns1:label>
</ns1:choice>
</ns1:choices>
</ns1:multipleChoiceQuestion>
<ns1:inputQuestion id="search_box">
<ns1:inputTypes>
<ns1:input type="TEXT_ALPHANUMERIC"/>
</ns1:inputTypes>
<ns1:label dir="ltr">
<ns1:text>Search type:</ns1:text>
</ns1:label>
</ns1:inputQuestion>
</ns1:questions>
</ns1:getQuestionsResponse>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

xsd file:

```
<xs:element name="questions">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="multipleChoiceQuestion"/>
                <xs:element ref="inputQuestion"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="contentListRef" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
            <xs:element ref="label"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

WSDL can be accessed [here](https://pastebin.com/cwLWQvRq)

Comment: `contentListRef` does not exist in the WSDL though I guess that is relevant

Comment: @RiggsFolly since `contentListRef` is not a 'ref' element is it necessary to be in WSDL? I have another call which returns a 'non-ref' element like `contentListRef` even though it does not exist in WSDL.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Also WSDL is missing `multipleChoiceQuestion` but I am getting that value. I guess WSDL shows the response would be `questions` and the xsd shows the schema of `questions`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify and fix the issue. The issue was with the xsd and data structure not matching.

A dummy response from the server was

```
$questions = [
        'multipleChoiceQuestion' => ['label'=>['text'=>'testtxt'],'choices'=>['choice'=>[['label'=>['text'=>'basic','dir'=>'ltr'],'id'=>'search_type_basic']]]],
        'inputQuestion'          => '',
        'contentListRef'         => 'L100',
        'label'                  => ['text'=>'testtxt1'],
    ];
```

I tweaked the xsd file and it worked

```
<xs:element name="questions">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element ref="multipleChoiceQuestion"/>
            <xs:element ref="inputQuestion"/>
            <xs:element name="contentListRef" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
            <xs:element ref="label"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```